# Remove single quotes in the array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.test.find().pretty();
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63b84e6d5bc77784ee5ecdf6"),
    demographic: { first_name: 'Srikanth', last_name: 'R' },
    change_history: '[{"change":"Gold"},{"change":"Silver"}]'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("63b84e6d5bc77784ee5ecdf7"),
    demographic: { first_name: 'Sri', last_name: 'K' },
    change_history: '[{"change":"Gold"},{"change":"Platinum"}]'
  }
]
```

May I know how to remove the single quotes in the `change_history`. that needs to be an array actually

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo DB aggregation pipeline: convert string to document/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210201/mongo-db-aggregation-pipeline-convert-string-to-document-object)

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the first step would be to find out what created `"change_history"` as a string and fix that.

The easiest way to `update` the current documents might be to use a `"$function"` in a pipeline and let javascript `parse` the string, like this.

```js
db.test.update(
{
  "change_history": {"$type": "string"}
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "change_history": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(chgHist) {return JSON.parse(chgHist)}",
          "args": ["$change_history"],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{"multi": true}
)
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("63b84e6d5bc77784ee5ecdf6"),
    "change_history": [
      {"change": "Gold"},
      {"change": "Silver"}
    ],
    "demographic": {
      "first_name": "Srikanth",
      "last_name": "R"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("63b84e6d5bc77784ee5ecdf7"),
    "change_history": [
      {"change": "Gold"},
      {"change": "Platinum"}
    ],
    "demographic": {
      "first_name": "Sri",
      "last_name": "K"
    }
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lwse6pDZEPh).